# grab image displayed on the UIImagePickerController without the overlay

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using UIImagePickerController with the camera as the sourceType. I am also drawing a custom overlay on the picker using the built-in overlay functionality(picker.overlay = myOverlay).

How can I get an UIImage of the camera, excluding my overlay?. I tried using UIGetScreenImage() but that captures my overlay as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
[picker takePicture];
```